# custom wordpress theme blog page always not showing the last two pages of the articles

Tags: theme-development, blog-page

custom wordpress theme blog page always not showing the last two pages of the articles, always sending in the last two pages to 404 page

Anyone can give me a light. I create a theme, using the theme processing before guttenberg, I use elementor pro also and the blog page is created by elementor, however the last two pages of the articles always going to 404 page